# data crawled is repeated when exporting to csv

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl the data from this [web](https://www.vietnamworks.com/tim-viec-lam/tat-ca-viec-lam) 
 My idea is crawling all the links on the web, then use `for` to send the request to each link to get the detailed data. 
 This is my [code](https://github.com/gialuong2801/abc/blob/main/demo), as you see I use selenium web driver to open the URL then use beautiful soup to crawl the data. 
 
 Well
it worked quite successfully, but while it is exported to the CSV file, the categories from `upload_date` to the `number_employees` of the links under the 1st one are the same as the 1st as the following 
 [image] 
 the `upload_date` to the `number_employees` in each link are presented in the page as this box [image].
 How should I sell this problem? 
 Sincerely thanks. <3
P/s: I have one more problem is I need to log in to the web to crawl the `salary` in each link but I've not found the answer yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to save the data scraped you append always the same value in the loop, here:

```
upload_date = content[0]
position = content[1]
career = content[2]
skill = content[3]
language_of_cv = content[4]
detail_address = content[5]
number_employees = content[6]
```

You  have to move through the data scraped in order to save everything in the csv file.

Comment: well, thanks, i tried to append each category to an empty list then clear the `content`, and it works <3